# How to determine whether healthy Windows 10 partition safe to delete

Tags: windows-10, disk-management

I deleted a volume on my HP 15-g088ca laptop and would like to extend the c: drive to the resulting 18.2GB of unallocated space but have a 1.69GB healthy primary partition in the way (see screen grab). The 1.69GB partition is listed as not having the boot, file page, and crash dump, but I don't know what's on it.

Should I be very afraid to delete this? It's my PC, which started out as a Windows 8.0/8.1 machine, so possible it was left over from a prior OS, or maybe I installed a dual boot at one time. Regardless, my data's all backed up, so as long as it doesn't brick the PC, I'm OK with losing whatever's on it.

I googled and found lots of hits for adding and deleting partitions but nothing about how to determine whether the partition I want to delete could have system files that would brick my PC if deleted.

[image]

Comment: Could someone please tell me why my OP got downvoted?

Comment: What research have you done prior to posting your question?

Comment: I googled and found lots of hits for adding and deleting partitions but nothing about how to determine whether the partition I want to delete could have system files that would brick my PC if deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally critical system-generated partitions will be near the beginning of the drive, so this is *likely* not critical.  However, the partition is NTFS, so you could try assigning it a drive letter to review the contents before making that determination.  If you don't see any contents, try showing hidden & system files.  Or you could run a tool such as Recuva (I have no relationship) to see what used to be there.

Comment: Worked great. Assigned a drive letter as suggested and not much on it. Right-clicked to delete and got warning that it was created by a non-Windows OS, so must have been some linux stuff I was doing a while back.

Comment: Great to hear it was helpful.  A note for future readers: Recuva or any other similar tool can recover files from the area of the hard drive where the partition lives, but there's no guarantee that those files were created *after* the current partition.  They could be artifacts from prior partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have done any dual installations or if you are using two OS in the same system, one in Windows and another in Linux. Then during the installation of Linux, you may have created this healthy partition with others. So when you try to delete this partition you may see some message log that it was not created by windows. It means this partition was created by Linux and some of the Linux files can be still running there. So it's safe to delete it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).